# File Upload using spring rest and axios, no multipart boundary was found

Tags: reactjs, spring, file-upload, axios, multipartform-data

I have some issues in file uploading using spring rest and react and axios,
my back-end code is

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

and I can upload file using postman, but by using axios I got some errors.

> nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

here is my code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: url,
  data: {
    formData
  }
})
```

also if I put

```
headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
```

I got error too,
can anyone tell me what are my mistakes please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be beacause you are creating a new object and sending the data inside the object
Try this  `data: formData`

Answer (score 1):

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: url,
  data: {  formData},
{...axios.default.headers,
...{headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }}

}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to put any headers as it will automatically , decides the parameters of headers , when you do it manually you need to explicitly decides few parameters which is quite difficult to judge , so dont give headers

Comment: Thank you for your response, Yes, exactly, either I did not put any headers, I could not connect to back-end.